# I can not start the server in any way due to problems with installing libraries and starting wheels

Tags: python, django, installation, server, module

I need to run this server on Django and React
https://github.com/ozoneplatform/ozone/releases/tag/v8.0.0.0-GA
I cloned it to myself, went to the "ozone-framework-python-server" folder, created a virtual environment and tried to install the libraries "pip install -r requirements.txt", but I got such errors
I work for Windows

```
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml, psycopg2-binary
  Building wheel for lxml (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [97 lines of output]

   - - -


      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      *********************************************************************************
      Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      *********************************************************************************
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
  Building wheel for psycopg2-binary (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1

    - - - 

     
      It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.
     
      You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
      If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
      required for the build and try again.
     
      For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
      <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).
     
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> psycopg2
```

At first I had to install c++ tols, then following the advice I tried to use the old version of pip, but nothing worked.I tried installing the "wheels" library, but that didn't help either. I don't understand much about this, but I really need to get this server up and running. Can you please tell me what I did wrong?

In the errors I noticed this line

```
      DEPRECATION: psycopg2 is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible rep
lacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
```

I also tried to do it with this command
" pip install --use-pep517 -r requirements.txt."
And got this result

```
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
Failed to build lxml psycopg2
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lxml, psycopg2, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I think this is due to the fact that that project has not been updated for a long time and some version conflicts have occurred there, but I don’t know how to fix it

Comment: 'then following the advice I tried to use the old version of pip" I think that is the opposite of what you want to do - I would first try upgrading pip to the latest version

Comment: nothing has changed, exactly there are errors when running the "wheels" of some packages (lxml, psycopg2)